# JasperReports - xml datasource

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports, ireport

I have xml with following structure as datasource:

```
...
<addresses>
   <address>
       <!--... first address... -->
       <country>
           <shortName>Belarus</shortName>
           <name>Republic of Belarus</name>
       </country>
       ...
   </address>
   <address>
       ... more adresses ...
       <country>
           <shortName>Russia</shortName>
           <name>Russian Federation</name>
       </country>
       ... same fields ...
   </address>
</addresses>
...
```

So I need to write jrxml template that gets the **last** address in addresses. When I use

```
<field name="regAddress_country_nameRu" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription>
        <![CDATA[addresses/address/country/shortName]]>
    </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

It gets "Belarus" - value from **first** address, but how to get values from **last** address?
I need to do it in *iReport*, so maybe I can do in GUI-style? Any solution will suit me well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
You can use function *last()* in XPATH expressions as pointed [here](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths). So to get las address in my example just need to modify expression:

```
<![CDATA[addresses/address[last()]/country/shortName]]>
```

It worked for me and I hope it will be helpful for you too **:)**.